# No output from printing linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

This is the code I have written for a linked list. Basically it just takes input and print it. At compile time it gives no error but also it gives no output. I am not getting what is wrong with this code? Help me out.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct list {
  int data;
  struct list* next;
};

insert(struct list* node, int data)
{
  node = malloc(sizeof(struct list*));
  if (node == NULL)
    node = data;
  else   
    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;
 return node;
}

printlist(struct list* node)
{
 if (node == NULL) 
   printf("Empty list\n");
 while(node->next != NULL)
   printf("the list contains %d", node->data);
   node = node->next;
}

main()
{
  struct list* NODE;
  NODE = malloc(sizeof(struct list*));
  insert(NODE, 3);
  insert(NODE, 5);
  printlist(NODE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it's because you don't keep the pointer of your node when you do and also remove the `*`

```
node=malloc(sizeof(struct list*));
```

try something like:

```
struct list *   insert(struct list* node ,int data)
    {
      struct list * new_elem = malloc(sizeof(*new_elem)); //check !=NULL
       new_elem->data = data;
       new_elem->next = NULL;
       if (node != NULL)
          node->next = new_elem;
     return (new_elem);
}
```

Comment: +1 first error you point out also present in main(), second `node=data; // incompatible types`  in `insert()` function (add this 2 points also), My answer is not complete hence deleting.

Answer (score 1):

actually,it contains many mistakes.

rewrite the insert():

```
struct list* insert(struct list* node ,int data) //need the type of return value 
{
    struct list* newnode;
    newnode=malloc(sizeof(struct list)); //get rid of '*'
    //how to insert to a link list? I suggest you make it understand.
    //in this code, I insert an element in the head.
    newnode->data = data;
    //if (node==NULL)
    //    newnode->next = NULL;
    //else 
    //    newnode->next=node;
    //the code above equals:
    newnode->next = node;
    return newnode;
}
```

and in printlist(), you can't make some code a block with space rather than ";" , that's to say,change

```
 while(node!=NULL) 
    printf("the list contains %d\n",node->data);
    node=node->next;
```

to

```
while(node!=NULL) {
    printf("the list contains %d\n",node->data);
    node=node->next;
}
```

the same mistake existed in the old insert().

althoght without the type of return value of printlist(),it can be compiled, but I suggest add one to it, like `void`.

in addition, for a null list,you need change:

```
if (node==NULL) 
 printf("Empty list\n");
```

to

```
if (node==NULL) {
   printf("Empty list\n");
   return;
```

}

with this new insert(), the main() will be:

```
main()
{
    struct list* NODE = NULL;
    NODE = insert(NODE,3);
    NODE = insert(NODE,5);
    printlist(NODE);
}
```

I have test that after this fix, it works.

Comment: Yes its working now :) thnks!!

Comment: @user2456752 well,there is another bug left acutally, which I have edited below begins with "in addition, for a null list,you need change..."

Comment: @user2456752 and for `malloc()`, you may need a `#include <stdlib.h>`